# Filtering by multiple items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter the list of items in `state.items` by adding items from `state.filterItems` to my `state.filter` array

if I use `this.state.items.filter(items => items.cat === 'veg' )` of course this works but I need to be able to filter dynamically using the list of items added to my `state.filter` array and I'm not sure how to do this,

I would also like to be able select multiple options and then hit a button to apply the filters rather than selecting them one by one

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KoCT_DiT2CNLz8ddr4O

**Hello.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import update from 'immutability-helper'
import TodoList from './TodoList'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import FilterList from './FilterList'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  max-width:1280px;
  background: papayawhip;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:20px;
`

const Grid = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
`

const Cell = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  padding: 20px;
`

export default class hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {id: 1, cat: 'fruit', text: 'apples'},
        {id: 2, cat: 'fruit', text: 'oranges'},
        {id: 3, cat: 'fruit', text: 'peaches'},
        {id: 4, cat: 'veg', text: 'carrots'},
        {id: 5, cat: 'veg', text: 'aubergine'},
        {id: 6, cat: 'veg', text: 'peaches'},
        {id: 7, cat: 'bread', text: 'olive bread'},
        {id: 8, cat: 'bread', text: 'bread roll'},
        {id: 9, cat: 'bread', text: 'bagel'},
      ],
      filterItems: [
        {id: 1, text: 'bread'},
        {id: 2, text: 'fruit'},
        {id: 3, text: 'vegetables'},
      ],
      filter: [
        {text: 'bread'}
      ],
    }
  }

  handleFilterChange = (filter) => {
    this.setState({filter: filter})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <div>
        <FilterList
          value={this.state.filter}
          onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
          filterItems={this.state.filterItems}
        />
        </div>
        <Grid>
          {
            this.state.items.filter(items => items.cat === 'veg', 'fruit' )
            .map(item =>
              <Cell>
                {console.log(this.state.filter.text)}
                <div>{item.cat}</div>
                <div>{item.text}</div>
              </Cell>
            )
          }
        </Grid>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}

//  <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4)} </pre>
```

FilterList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
import update from 'immutability-helper'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const FilterListBg = styled.div`
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
`

const FilterListItem = styled.div`
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  padding:10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff00ff;
`

const FilterBg = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height:40px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top:20px;
`

const FilterItem = styled.div`
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  padding:10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff00ff;
`
export default class FilterList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      search: ''
    }
  }
  handleAdd = (item) => {
      const value = update(this.props.value, {
          $push: [
            {
            text: item,
            id: Math.random(),
            }
          ]
      })
      this.props.onChange(value)
    }

  handleRemove = (index) => {
      const value = update(this.props.value, {
        $splice: [
          [index, 1]
        ]
      })
      this.props.onChange(value)
    }

  handleFilterUpdate = event => {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.handleFilterUpdate}
          placeholder="Hledat podle nazvu"
        />
        {this.state.search}
        <FilterListBg>
          {
            this.props.filterItems.filter(items => items.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
            .map((item,cat,index) =>
              <FilterListItem key={item.id} onClick={()=>this.handleAdd(item.text)}>
                {item.text}
              </FilterListItem>
            )
          }
        </FilterListBg>
        Aktivní filtry
        <FilterBg>
          {
            this.props.value.map((item, index) =>
            <FilterItem key={item.id} onClick={this.handleRemove}>
              {item.text}
            </FilterItem>
            )
          }
        </FilterBg>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to *show* the items matching your `filterList`, shouldn't something simple like this work?

```
const filterTexts = this.state.filter.map(item => item.text);
const itemsToShow = this.state.items.filter(
                      item => filterTexts.indexOf(item.cat) !== -1);
```

And then you can map over `itemsToShow` to create your Cells.

If you want a one-liner to simply copy-paste:

```
this.state.items.filter(items => this.state.filterItems.map(item => item.text)
                          .indexOf(items.cat) !== -1 )
    .map(item =>
        <Cell>
            {console.log(this.state.filter.text)}
            <div>{item.cat}</div>
            <div>{item.text}</div>
        </Cell>
    )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Yes I want to show the items in my `state.filter` that match the items in `state.filterList` once they've been added to `state.filter`. I have added this to my webpackbin and it doesn't seem to filter by what's selected

Comment: Can you try using the first solution where the lists are saved as variables first, then console.log those and tell me what the output is?

Comment: in filterTexts = `(3) ["bread", "fruit", "vegetables"]
0
:
"bread"
1
:
"fruit"
2
:
"vegetables"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: itemsToShow = `(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, cat: "fruit", text: "apples"}
1
:
{id: 2, cat: "fruit", text: "oranges"}
2
:
{id: 3, cat: "fruit", text: "peaches"}
3
:
{id: 7, cat: "bread", text: "olive bread"}
4
:
{id: 8, cat: "bread", text: "bread roll"}
5
:
{id: 9, cat: "bread", text: "bagel"}
length
:
6
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: Is this not the desired functionality? You now have a list of all items that matched the filter, and you can run your `map()` function on it to create your JSX elements.

As a sidenote, you have called it `vegetables` in the filters and `veg` in the `items.cat`. You'll either have to choose one and stick with it or write some logic to map from one to the other. I can help with that if you want to keep them different for some reason.

Comment: Well, no this isn't really the way it should work, there is no items that have been added `state.filter` yet it is showing ["bread", "fruit", "veg"] (it should be veg) and the array should be empty as no filters have been applied. It also doesn't filter at the moment. Again I've added this to the webpack so you can see what it's doing

Comment: ah ok so I have this almost working, instead of  `this.state.filterItems.map(item => item.text);` it should be  `this.state.filter.map(item => item.text);` so now it shows the items that match the filter , but what I actually need is to show all of the items initially and then filter out by the selected filter

Comment: I'm confused. What's the difference between filterItems and filter? I thought the filterItems state contained the items you wanted to show.

In any case, if you want to start by showing everything and then removing them with buttons, it would probably be best to reverse your logic: All items in state.filter should **not** be showed. So state.filter starts as an empty array, and you swap the `filterTexts.indexOf(item.cat) !== -1);` with `filterTexts.indexOf(item.cat) === -1);`. Adding items to state.filter then does what you want.

Comment: I'm confused to , not explaining very well sorry. Basically the filterItems is just a list of different filter options that are selectable. Once clicked on they will be added to the filter array and this then defines what is shown and what isn't. I map through the filterItems in the FilterList.js and don't need to map through them again as all logic is taken care of

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148333/discussion-between-finnss-and-tom-harrison).